# Losing the source branch of triggering build pipeline in Azure DevOps deployment pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, I have two Git repositories in the MyProject project:

- MyProject.Web is the .NET Core server-side code for an Angular application.
- MyProject.UI is the associated Angular project.

Pull requests to specified branches in both of those projects trigger a build pipeline. The pipeline YAML files are in the MyProject.Web repo. Successful completion of the build pipeline triggers a deployment pipeline. The build is working fine; the deployment is fine when a MyProject.Web branch is the trigger, but it isn't always doing what's expected when a MyProject.UI branch is the trigger.

## Details

We currently have three deployment environments: Dev, QA, Test.

I have a build pipeline that pulls the code from each of these repos together and builds the application (into a Docker image, for what it's worth).
That pipeline is triggered by completed pull requests to any master or main or release/* branch in either the Web or UI repo. (In the Web project, it's master;
in the UI project, it's main). Whether the trigger comes from the Web repo or the UI repo, the pipeline knows to combine it with the corresponding branch
from the other repo (i.e., master with main, main with master, release/1.0 with release/1.0, release/1.2 with release/1.2, etc.).

I have a deployment pipeline that is triggered by completion of the build pipeline. It has one stage per deployment environment It is *supposed* to know whether the source branch was master or main or whether it was a release/* branch.

- If it was master or main, it should deploy to Dev and, after manager approval, to QA. It should never deploy to Test.
- If it was a release/* branch, it should deploy, after manager approval, to Test. It should never deploy to Dev or QA.

## Expectations in Each Triggering Scenario

Here is a summary of my expectations/requirements for each possible type of build trigger, and the reality in the deployment in the fourth scenario.

| *Triggering Project* | *Triggering Branch* | *MyProject.Web Branch to Build* | *MyProject.UI Branch to Build* | *MyProject.Web Branch to Deploy From* | *Environment(s) to Deploy To* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MyProject.Web | master | master | main | master | Dev, QA |
| MyProject.Web | release/1.0 | release/1.0 | release/1.0 | release/1.0 | Test |
| MyProject.UI | main | master | main | master | Dev, QA |
| MyProject.UI | release/1.0 | release/1.0 | release/1.0 | release/1.0 ❌ (reality: seems to pull from master) | Test ❌ (reality: deploys to Dev, QA) |

## The Problem

My setup performs as expected, as set out in the table, *except* for the deployment process for the final case. While I can tell from the DevOps pipeline logs that the builds are
correctly choosing the branches to get the code from in all four scenarios, the deployment in the final scenario seems to be taking a build associated
with the MyProject.Web *master* branch (the log *shows* that the pipeline was run against master) and it is deploying whatever build it's finding on master to Dev and QA *instead of* to Test.

Any thoughts about what's going on here? Guidance for a solution? Details below.

## The Pipeline Files

Three pipeline files come into play here:

- docker-build.yml, the YAML file behind a pipeline named Docker-Build.

  - It resides in MyProject.Web.
  - It is triggered by completed pull requests to master or release/* branches on MyProject.Web.
  - It is also triggered by completed PRs to main or release/* branches on MyProject.UI.
  - After setting things up and setting template parameter values, the meat of its work is performed by an invoked pipeline template, but there's no need to go into that here.
- kubernetes-deploy.yml, the YAML file behind a pipeline named Kubernetes-Deploy.

  - It resides in MyProject.Web.
  - It is triggered by successful completion of Docker-Build.
  - After setting things up and setting one template parameter value (the pipeline ID of the associated Docker-Build pipeline), it invokes the pipeline template *deploy-pipeline-template.yml*, discussed next.
- deploy-pipeline-template.yml, a pipeline template.

  - It is shared by multiple applications/repos in this same project.
  - It resides in a separate repository called MyProject.Pipeline.

The content of these files, with extraneous omissions noted:

docker-build.yml:

```
# This is the YAML for the "Docker-Build" pipeline. It resides in the MyProject.Web repository.
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Web
      trigger:
        - master
        - release/*
    - repository: UiRepo
      type: git
      name: MyProject.UI
      trigger:
        - main
        - release/*
    - repository: PipelineRepo
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Pipeline

# [variables and pool omitted]

steps:
  - ${{ if in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master', 'main') }}:
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web@refs/heads/master
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.UI@refs/heads/main
  - ${{ if not(in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master', 'main')) }}:
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.Web@${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
    - checkout: git://MyProject/MyProject.UI@${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

# [some details omitted]

  - template: build-pipeline-template.yml@PipelineRepo
    parameters:
      relativeSolutionPath: MyProject.Web
      relativeProjectPath: MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web
      # [other parameters omitted]
```

kubernetes-deploy.yml:

```
  repositories:
    - repository: PipelineRepo
      type: git
      name: MyProject.Pipeline
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: buildPipeline
      source: 'Docker-Build'
      trigger: true

trigger:
  - none

# [pool omitted]

stages:
  - template: deploy-pipeline-template.yml@PipelineRepo
    parameters:
      buildPipelineId: '123'
# I can probably replace '123' with variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.PipelineID'] or the
# same thing with another one of Azure DevOps' multitudinous syntaxes, but I haven't tested it yet.
```

build-pipeline-template.yml

```
# This is a pipeline template that resides in the MyProject.Pipeline repository.
parameters:
  - name: buildPipelineId
    displayName: ID of the pipeline that produced the artifacts to download
    type: string

stages:
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      stageName: Development
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), in(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/main'))
      variableGroup: myproject-web-variables-dev
      buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
      devOpsEnvironment: myproject-dev
      kubernetesServiceConnection: myproject-dev-kubeconfig
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      stageName: QA
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), in(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/main'))
      variableGroup: myproject-web-variables-qa
      buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
      devOpsEnvironment: myproject-qa
      kubernetesServiceConnection: myproject-dev-kubeconfig
  - template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
    parameters:
      stageName: Test
      canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
      variableGroup: myproject-web-variables-test
      buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
      devOpsEnvironment: myproject-test
      kubernetesServiceConnection: myproject-dev-kubeconfig
```

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but if you're building true microservices, shouldn't they both build and deploy independently from one another? It seems like all this is doing is pushing you down the path to having a distributed monolith.

Comment: That's a good point, but at the beginning of the project it had been countered that keeping the UI on a separate service from the supporting back end would entail authentication problems. I suspect that that could have been worked out but this is the way we went ahead with it. For what it's worth, this Web app is a thin back-end for the UI, and all the other work *is* farmed out by it to other services.

Comment: Based on Daniel's comment, building separately might also be a suggestion worth trying. And about the "authentication problem", it can also create a build service account for builds/pipelines to help keep the consistent authentication.